# Sinatra Github OAuth Problems

Tags: ruby, github, oauth, sinatra

I am using the [`sinatra_auth_github`](https://github.com/atmos/sinatra_auth_github) gem to try and put GitHub OAuth into my Sinatra app. I was testing using the [`sinatra-auth-github-test`](https://github.com/atmos/sinatra-auth-github-test) example app for a while and it worked. I went back to try and get some of that code to work in my app and though most of it worked, the redirect from GitHub doesn't.

Can anyone recommend anything to help?

Here's the code:

```
class SimpleApp < Sinatra::Base
  # [...]

  set :github_options, {
    :scope     => 'user',
    :secret    => ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET'],
    :client_id => ENV['GITHUB_CLIENT_ID'],
  }
  register Sinatra::Auth::Github

  get '/' do
    erb :index
  end

  get '/login' do
    authenticate!
    "Hello there, #{github_user.login}!"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the issue you're experiencing is related to [`shotgun`](http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/development/shotgun#label-Shotgun). This gem reloads your entire application on every request, so it's possible there's an issue with maintaining the OAuth-login session state across the login-related requests.

Running your application with `rackup` instead (as in the example app), I don't experience any problems:

```
bundle exec rackup -p 3000
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing that and I'm getting the same result. Is it because the way I'm calling `/login` is from an `href` in `index.erb`? Is it because the Redirect URL in the Github app is set to `/`? @wjordan

Comment: @zander in order to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I or others can reproduce your issue, please add more complete contents of the Sinatra source code you're running, and the exact commands you're using to run your server in development. I'm curious how the `GITHUB_` environment variables are provided and if that's consistent between your test app and this one.

Comment: As seen in the code above, I am using a client ID and client secret from GitHub and what I listed above is pretty much all I have, I just left out the index.erb because that's just an href linking to `/login`. In terms of the server, I'm running `bundle exec shotgun -p 3000` and the redirect link is just `http://0.0.0.0:3000`, if I try to set it to `http://0.0.0.0:3000/login`, an error shows up that the redirect URI is incorrect. It is going to Github normally, but the response link is not sending the user back to the Sinatra app @wjordan

Comment: The code is in a class in an `app.rb` file and the config.ru links to it but in an example I [saw](https://github.com/atmos/sinatra-auth-github-test/blob/master/config.ru) it was working in a config.ru @wjordan

Comment: have you tried calling `enable :sessions` within your Sinatra app?

Comment: yeah its been in there the entire time

Comment: Until you provide a complete example I can run locally and reproduce your issue (e.g., a public GitHub repo I can clone), I can't help any further, sorry.

Comment: @zander with the actual code I managed to narrow down your issue to the use of `shotgun`. it works when using `rackup`. hope that helps!

Comment: Great, glad to hear it worked! If this answer helped solve your question, the last step is to [mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/327137). Welcome to Stack Overflow!